# Volusion Category template generated dynamically

Tags: html, css, templates, dynamic, volusion

I am new to Volusion and want to be able to add unique id to each product div, table and image section while in the category page.

For more understanding please see this link: http://v2283470.kdqp7pdbwqns.demo48.volusion.com/category-s/101.htm

I would like to have each product div, paragraph and table have an id generated dynamically by concatenating a given id with the product code (product id).

Comment: Would you possible expand on this and explain what your goal is by doing so. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: @user357034  Assuming i have two table elements:  `<table class="table" id="products-table"></table>
`  `<table class="table" id="products-table"></table>
`     i want to be able to append elements to the tables based on an id. can i get something like this from Volusion:  `<table class="table" id="products-table-product-code-1"></table>`  `<table class="table" id="products-table-product-code-2"></table>` so that i can append table rows to correct table via jquery

Comment: To me more clear, I mean what do you want to accomplish with this new structure. How does this help you? You currently have a responsive deign. Adding tables is counterproductive to that.

Comment: @user357034 table is needed to present product data in tabular form. Thanks anyway i have been able to see through the control panel where to fix that.